# Documentation Framework like JavaDoc for Objective C

Tags: objective-c, documentation-generation

Does Objective C have a documentation framework similar to JavaDoc where documentation can be generated from the source code?

Comment: There isn't one specific to Objective-C, but I use Doxygen. Apple uses HeaderDoc, but pretty much nobody else does anymore.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Doxygen!](http://www.doxygen.nl/) You can use it for many languages, including Objective-c

Comment: Definitely the best option. If you'd like to go even further, I've written a script that will convert Doxygen's output to look more like Apple's API docs: http://github.com/mattball/doxyclean

Answer (score 10):

Good news for all! :D Finally after waiting a long time Apple has introduced a parser comments for our projects. According to the [new features](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_5_0.html) in XCode 5:

> Project documentation from framework API reference documentation and
>   structured comments in your own source code are displayed in the quick
>   help panel and in code completion popover views. Doxygen and HeaderDoc
>   structured comments are supported formats.

and from the [Clang 3.2](http://llvm.org/releases/3.2/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#majorfeatures) release notes:

> Clang parses the comments and can detect syntactic and semantic errors
>   in comments. These warnings are off by default. Pass -Wdocumentation
>   flag to enable warnings about documentation comments.

If you want to see an example of this new feature I recommend you take a look at the following article: [Documentation in Xcode 5](http://confusatory.org/post/63488534619/documentation-in-xcode-5?utm_source=iOS%20Dev%20Weekly&utm_campaign=iOS_Dev_Weekly_Issue_115&utm_medium=email)

Answer (score 6):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) is quite popular among Obj-C developers.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a look to [HeaderDoc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/intro/intro.html) wich is the apple documentation framework similar to Java.

Answer (score 1):

Appledoc has become very popular. . . version 1 was based on Doxygen, whereas version 2 was written from the ground up.

It doesn't quite have all the features of Doxygen (charts, enums, C++ classes, etc), but what it does offer is beautifully formatted docs in HTML of IDE integrated format.

Also interesting to note is the following:

- The CocoaPods tool includes Appledoc documentation for the libraries that it installs. Quite handy.