# What's the RDoc for iOs?

Tags: ios, documentation-generation

[RDOC](http://rdoc.sourceforge.net/) creates documentation from Ruby Source Files. Is there something similar for iOs? It's probably obvious and I just used the wrong phrases on Google...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used myself, but apparently [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) works for Objective-C code (it doesn't matter what platform you're deploying to, since it's documentation).

See also this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911427/documentation-framework-like-javadoc-for-objective-c).